# xlrd missing in GCP AI notebooks

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, xlrd

Since today, every AI notebook I provision seems to be missing xlrd. Installing it with conda lands me in package hell: Trying to load an xlsx. First error: xlrd missing, install it. After installing xlrd: the current version (>=2) only supports xls, not xlsx.

One of the reasons I'm using GCP AI platform notebooks is this used to be hassle free. Does anyone have a fix or knowledge what is going on?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platform, but `pandas` will use `openpyxl` for xlsx files if you have it installed. Try installing that if it's not installed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the this [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/2.0.1/) `xlrd` library will no longer read anything other than .xls files. They recommend to look in [Working with Excel Files in Python](http://www.python-excel.org/) to check alternatives to xlsx files. As @ArthurBorshenko commented in your question, `openpyxl` is one option.

To install dependencies in AI Platform Notebooks follow the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/dependencies).